# How to adapt my code in TranslateModule.forRoot

Tags: angular

I got the project from a friend, In fac, I just have to create a multi language.

In HTML, I created this:

```html
<div class="languageSelect" style="color: aqua;">
    <a (click)="switchLang('nl')">NL</a>
    <span> | </span>
    <a (click)="switchLang('en')">EN</a>
    <span> | </span>
</div>
```

In TS

Here is my code

```js
constructor(
    public _router: Router,
    private LS: LocalStoreService,
    public _location: Location,
    private translate: TranslateService ) {
        translate.addLangs(['en', 'nl', 'fr']);
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');
}
    
switchLang(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
    console.log(42);
}
```

For now, it's ok... Now, I have to create a `TranslateModule.forRoot({`

I would like to add this code

```js
TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: httpTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    })
] /,
```

But, how I could adapt my code with the code from my friend below?

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true, relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: TranslateModule should be imported as any other module, so you would append your whole TranslateModule.forRoot({...}) code into the imports array.

Comment: The code you pasted from your friend looks like it's part of the `AppRoutingModule` (or another routing module for that matter). Please make sure you import the `TranslateModule.forRoot` thing inside the `AppModule` imports array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "," at the end, and import new modules.

Change

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true, relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

to

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true, relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' }),
        TranslateModule, /*<--- Don't forget to import this too*/
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
           loader: {
               provide: TranslateLoader,
               useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
               deps: [HttpClient]
           }
        }),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

EDITED =================================
I share with you some code, maybe you can solve your problem with this. As I comment below,you need to create a json file in the folder assets/i18n with the exact same name that you use in the language configuration. In my case `'lang_english.json'`

app.module.ts

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { LangSelectorComponent } from './components/common/lang-selector/lang-selector.component';


export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LangSelectorComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
    TranslateModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpClient
  ],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

lang-selector.component.ts

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { LanguagesService } from 'src/app/_services/languages.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lang-selector',
  templateUrl: `
    <div class="btn-group pull-right" *ngIf="!inline">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bolder">{{langText}}</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm dropdown-menu-right">
          <ul class="nav nav-hover flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let lang of langs"><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="change_lang(lang.id)" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-text">{{lang.name}}</span></a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div" *ngIf="inline">
      <a href='javascript:void(0)' (click)="change_lang('lang_english')">English</a> / <a href='javascript:void(0)' (click)="change_lang('lang_spanish')">Spanish</a>  
  </div>
`
})
export class LangSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() inline:boolean = false;

  langText:string = 'English';

  langs = [
    {name:'English',id:'lang_english'},
    {name:'Spanish',id:'lang_spanish'},
  ]

  constructor( private translateService: TranslateService, private languageService: LanguagesService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.languageService.language.subscribe( lang => {
      if ( lang !== 'lang_english' ) this.langText = 'Spanish';
      else this.langText = 'English';
    })
  }

  change_lang( id:string ){
    this.languageService.change_lang( id );
  }

}
```

languages.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LanguagesService {

    private languageBehavior: BehaviorSubject<string>;
    public language: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private api: HttpClient, private translateService: TranslateService) {
      this.languageBehavior = new BehaviorSubject<string>(localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'lang_english');
      this.language = this.languageBehavior.asObservable();
      this.translateService.setDefaultLang(this.languageBehavior.value);
      this.translateService.use(this.languageBehavior.value);
    }

    get selectedLang(){return this.languageBehavior.value};

    change_lang(  id:string ){
      this.languageBehavior.next(id);
      localStorage.setItem('lang', id);
      this.translateService.use(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried, but I always have the same problem. The click works for the `NL` then when I click on `EN` it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, take care that you need to create a json file inside `assets/i18n` with the exact same name in your code (assets/i18n/en.json)

Comment: Hello Gonzalo, thank you for your time, I will wish to use your code. On [Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uopv9q?file=src/app/components/common/lang-selector/lang-selector.component.ts) I copied your code. I have a problem with the patch `Error in src/app/components/common/lang-selector/lang-selector.component.ts (7:16)`, did I miss a step? Thank you a lot...

Comment: Did you check the file path?